# check if cell ref is within a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

In a formula I'm using `OFFSET` to pull a value from another cell at a user defined offset:

```
OFFSET([@[last seen]],-$B$1,0)
```

I'd like to make sure that the resulting offset doesn't fall outside the current table (if so, default the value to 0).  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
=IF(ROW()-$B$1<ROW(Table2),0, OFFSET([@[last seen]],-$B$1,0))
```

where `Table2` is the name of the data table, and `$B$2` is the cell containing the offset value.